Python 3.12 f2py linking against libraries not working properly
With Python 3.11 and the distutils backend I was able to easily compile one interface file and link to an archive with various other precompiled f90 files. Now with meson it seems like this is not possible anymore.
So I have two subroutines:
subroutine1.f90
subroutine subroutine1
    implicit none
    call subroutine2
    print *, "Inside subroutine1"
end subroutine subroutine1

and
subroutine2.f90
subroutine subroutine2
    implicit none
    print *, "Inside subroutine2"
end subroutine subroutine2

I compile both files with gfortran -c subroutine1.f90 subroutine2.f90 and put them into an archive by the command ar rcs libmylibrary.a subroutine1.o subroutine2.o. Lastly I have a main file
main.f90
subroutine main
    implicit none
    call subroutine1()
end subroutine main

and when I use f2py -c main.f90 -m inter -L. -lmylibrary.a I get the interface file. Trying to import the interface in my python file as import inter I get the error: ImportError: /home/XYZ/f2pytest/inter.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: subroutine1_ and for the life of me I can't figure out why this is not working anymore. When I use the python3.11 version of f2py it compiles no problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

You need:

Use -L"$(pwd)" instead of -L., because meson builds the module in a temporary directory, not in the current one;
Use -lmylibrary instead -lmylibrary.a, probably yours mistake.

For macOS:
$ python3.12 -m numpy.f2py -c main.f90 -m inter -L"$(pwd)" -lmylibrary
...
ninja: Entering directory `/private/var/folders/wy/z0gbkfgs7mv24ryqkdm90rm40009rh/T/tmpaj6e0z70/bbdir'
...
$ python3.12 -c "import inter; print(inter.__doc__); inter.main()"
This module 'inter' is auto-generated with f2py (version:1.26.4).
Functions:
    main()
.
 Inside subroutine2
 Inside subroutine1


What if there are a dynamic and a static versions of that library and I want the static one. For some reason -lmylib.a doesn't work and it always chooses the dynamic *.so one.

I see two options (since the meson build may have unexpected limitations). First, explicitly specifying the library file: /opt/lib/libmylib.a. Second, make a copy of only static library in a temporary directory for the build, for example, /tmp/dir, and use the keys: -L/tmp/dir -lmylib 
